# How to pass argument to a method without going through selector Swift?

Tags: swift, function, methods

I have an application in Swift that has multiple UISegmentedControls on a page, all of which have the same target, the method "answerClicked". However, I need a way to pass information through to this method saying WHICH UISegmentedControl was just clicked.

I know arguments can't be passed through selectors-- is there a way I can obtain this information and pass it through to the "answerClicked" method?

```
class Flowchart{
    //Init segmented controls up here...

    segmentedControl0.addTarget(self, action: #selector(answerClicked), for: .valueChanged)
    segmentedControl1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(answerClicked), for: .valueChanged)
    segmentedControl2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(answerClicked), for: .valueChanged)    

    @objc func answerClicked(){
        //Ideally would have an argument "segmentedControlNumber: Int"
        //How else to tell 0, 1, and 2 apart?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `tag` property for each of your `UISegmentedControl`s, and then use the `sender` which is sent as the first argument to the value changed method to get the `tag`:

```
class Flowchart {
    //Init segmented controls up here...

    func setup() {
        segmentedControl1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(answerClicked), for: .valueChanged)
        segmentedControl1.tag = 1

        segmentedControl2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(answerClicked), for: .valueChanged)
        segmentedControl2.tag = 2

        segmentedControl3.addTarget(self, action: #selector(answerClicked), for: .valueChanged)
        segmentedControl3.tag = 3  
    }  

    @objc func answerClicked(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        switch sender.tag {
        case 1:
            // code to handle segmentedControl1
        case 2:
            // code to handle segmentedControl2
        case 3:
            // code to handle segmentedControl3
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

---

Note:  As @rmaddy stated in the comments, it is best to avoid using tag `0` since all views receive the tag value `0` by default.  I renamed your segmented controls starting at `1`.

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly. You just saved me a ton of time and frustration.

Comment: It's best to avoid using an explicit tag of `0` since all views have a tag of `0` by default.

Answer (score 2):

Vacawama's answer works fine, and is a good fit for the question you're asking, but I advise against using tags. They're fragile. You have to remember to set the tags in your storyboard, and if you change things it's easy to forget to maintain them.

Instead, I would suggest using the sender in Vacawama's answer to figure out which control was tapped:

```
var controls: [UISegmentedControl]!

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  controls = [segmentedControl1, segmentedControl2, segmentedControl3]
}

@IBAction func answerClicked(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    if let index = controls.index( { where sender === $0 } ) {
       //act on your index
    } else {
       //error case; could not find sender in controls array. (Should not happen)
    }
}
```

#### Edit:

Or if you want to use a switch statement you can write it like this instead:

```
@IBAction func answerClicked(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
  switch sender {
     case segmentedControl1:
        //code for control 1
     case segmentedControl2:
        //code for control 2
     case segmentedControl3:
        //code for control 3
     default: 
        //error case
        //break
   }
}
```

Comment: And if the 3 segmented controls are actually outlets, make use of an outlet collection to get the array of controls.

Comment: @rmaddy, Except that the order of the items in an outlet collection is not guaranteed. The order is **usually** the order in which they are added to the collection, but sometimes not. I've been bitten by this before.

Comment: Interesting point. I never use storyboards or outlets so I hadn't considered that possible issue.

Comment: It's a very annoying feature of outlet collections that **severely** limits their usefulness.

Comment: `controls` needs to be a property instead of a local variable.  `controls.index(where: { sender === $0 } )`.  You don't have to set the `tag` in the Storyboard.  In my example they are set at the same time the target/action is assigned.

Comment: Good catch on the local var. That'll teach me to write code in the SO editor.

Comment: It's also true that you can set the tags in code, but tags are still fragile. In your particular case you could get away with it since you're interrogating sender.tag rather than using `viewWithTag()`